# Unable to start Apache Tomcat on Port 443 | The address is already in use

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I am trying to deploy one Java Web Application on tomcat 7. I want to use port 443 for the same.
But whenever I am starting the server getting error as below: **Address already in use : JVM Bind :: 443**

[image: I'm getting the error as: Address already in use]

I ran netstat command and it appears that the "system" process with PID 4 is holding the port 443. I cannot kill that process as well. Can anyone please help me on how to fix this issue?

Comment: There is probably a Webserver running, exposing HTTPS on port 443. Tomcats Connector is using port 8443 as default for HTTPS. Your fix should be to stop the other servic or to change the port for Tomcat. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: All comments and answers boil down to: some other application - service is already using port 443.  So shutdown your JVM (already done since it wont start), start a command prompt window, and do `netstat`.  Look at the ports in LISTEN, you should see an entry for port 443.  Then find which application is using that (and that is a Windows admin question, ask on Windows specific forum) and shut it down.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: FYI, you can run the command prompt window with administrator privileges and run `netstat -ab`, this will show you which executable is using which port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `net stop http` - this will stop the http service (and dependant services)

Comment: Assuming there is an HTTP service running.

Comment: Running this command helped me to start the Apache Tomcat server on properly.